# Changing DNS via Registry Key through Desktop Authority

Tags: windows-registry

I'm trying to set new DNS info over my network to multiple workstations through Desktop Authority, but I'm stumped at working around each workstations network adapters GUID in the registry.

[image: Where I'm at.]

This doesn't do anything for me ^

Is there a dynamic variable for GUID's?